# Are USAID datasets available for download?

Tags: usaidopen

I just signed up for an account to the DDL. I've tried to access three datasets and receive the same message in each instance; "You do not have permission to view this dataset". I've tried logging out and back in and receive the same message. Are all datasets posted to the DDL available for download and if so, am i receiving this message in error?

Comment: This forum is general to open data and I think in your case you should contact their support directly: dataservices@usaid.gov, or report it as a technical issue: https://github.com/USAID/USAID-Data-Services/issues

Comment: If you do get an answer that's *not* from this forum, please self-answer and mark the question "answered". That way the info is publicly available.

Comment: Just curious - what is the DDL?

Comment: opened an issue with USAID https://github.com/USAID/USAID-Data-Services/issues/30

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello Charles and thank you for your question.  Not all datasets on USAID's Development Data Library (DDL) [https://data.usaid.gov/] are publicly available for download.  Some are designated as private, intended for internal USAID use.  Please email dataservices@usaid.gov to request access to specific non-public datasets on the DDL and the team will begin work on your request.

Best wishes,
Morgan Daniels